# Dict to tuple : why does it not take all values?

Tags: python, tuples, hashable

I converted a dictionary to tuple so it can be hashable.

```
DATA_ILLUMINANTS = {
'LED': tuple({
    380.0: 0.006,
    385.0: 0.013,
    ...
    780.0: 0.108,})
    }
```

When I print the tuple, there is not the second column of data, it is :

```
(380.0, 385.0, 390.0, 395.0, 400.0, ... , 780.0)
```

Any idea why ?

I use the 'LED' tuple in another code that return me the following error : `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'` and I suppose this is because data are missing in the tuple.

Comment: Post code you used to convert and what you expected to get.

Comment: When you iterate over a dictionary, you iterate over its _keys_. What output were you expecting - `tuple({...}.items())`, maybe?

Comment: The "tuple object has no attribute 'shape'" error is symptomatic of that code needing a Numpy array, but that's another can of worms.

Comment: Dict values don't have to be hashable. Only the keys do. You could use the dict as is; no need to convert it to a tuple.

Comment: If you're converting a dict literal to a tuple, as in your example, why not simply use a tuple literal in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating over a dict (which is what e.g. `tuple()` does) iterates over the keys.

You'll want `tuple({...}.items())` to get a tuple of 2-tuples.

```
>>> x = {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}
>>> tuple(x)
(1, 3, 5)
>>> tuple(x.items())
((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))
>>>
```

Comment: Iteration order may be unpredictable. It would be wise to sort the items, too.

Comment: @JohnKugelman That depends on the version of CPython in use and OP's use case, but yep :)

Comment: @JohnKugelman effectively since CPython 3.6, and since Python 3.7+ officially, `dict` objects maintain insertion order.

Comment: Right, this is why I hedged with "may be". For clarity's sake, I recommend sorting.

Answer (score 1):

`tuple()` will iterate through the given object, here a dict. The dict iterate over the keys, this is why. You can force it to iterate over the items:
`tuple({ 380.0: 0.006, 385.0: 0.013, ... 780.0: 0.108,}.items() )`